# Rank with condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm searching for a formula which could rank a value from a subset of a range.

Let's say Col.A is Departement and Col.B is value.

I want a formula which can rank the value from all the other value of this departement.

I have tried things
 `{=rank(value,if(myrange=condition,myrange),0)}`
Does not work.

I have managed to do the oposite - retrieving the value of a certain rank with :

`{=small(if(myrange=condition,myrange),rank i want)}`

I don't understand why my first formula fail.

Excpected result would be the rank of the value from it's subset of value which is all cells where the condition is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such scenarios (ranking a subset of data), I find using `SUMPRODUCT` much easier:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12=A2)*(B2<$B$2:$B$12))+1
```

This is for descending order. Result:

[image]

Comment: Nice, same result, different answer. This uses arrays though.

Comment: I'm marking this one as answer but both your solutions worked. TY.keeping both way to do it in mind.

Answer (score 3):

> *Although Excel has a `RANK` function, there is no `RANKIF` function to
>   perform a conditional rank. However, you can easily create a
>   conditional `RANK` with the `COUNTIFS` function. [Exceljet](https://exceljet.net/formula/rank-if-formula)*

---

Some sample data:

```
| Dep | Val |
|-----|-----|
| A   | 5   |
| A   | 3   |
| A   | 6   |
| A   | 6   |
| B   | 3   |
| B   | 8   |
| B   | 2   |
| C   | 9   |
| C   | 5   |
| C   | 7   |
```

---

Let's put the `COUNTIFS` in there:

[image]

Formula in `C2` for descending:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,A2,$B$2:$B$11,">"&B2)+1
```

Formula in `D2` for ascending:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,A2,$B$2:$B$11,"<"&B2)+1
```

Drag both down....